# get the manifest.json file of a chrome web app

Tags: google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I made a chrome web store application and i lost the manifest.json file of the last version. Is there any way to get this file from the Developer Dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From the Developer Dashboard, click **More Info** for the app.
2. In the popup there is a link labeled **Download**: main.crx
3. Click the link to download your app's crx file.
4. Open the crx file in any zip file manager. It will include the manifest.json for the app.

Comment: Quick note: the manifest will include some extra, automatically added things! Like the `update_url` and (possibly) `key`. You may want to remove those before submitting a new version.